# iOS and Facebook Messenger security

Tags: ios, facebook

If the same Facebook Messenger account is opened on my device and on another device, and my device's Messenger app is allowed access to photos, can my device's photos be viewed or hacked on the other device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, another device cannot access your device's files/photos. That would require the other device to browse your device's files.